# How to use index match and if statements to adjust for percent increase

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match

I need to create a string for Excel that will include all the criteria.

If previous month's `% premium` (sheet 1 column c) is less than this months `% Premium` than apply the `% lift` (sheet 2 D3) to the `% Premium` (column c) in this  month to the number of `VDPS` (sheet 2 column b). If the previous month's `% premium` (sheet 1 column c) is greater than this month than back out `% lift` (sheet 2 D3), if equal than leave the same. All this needs to be matched on `ownerID`.

Sheet 1

```
a           B       C
Date        ownerID % Premium
2/29/2016   66393   100%
3/31/2016   66393   100%
2/29/2016   66732   100%
3/31/2016   66732   100%
2/29/2016   67065   0%
3/31/2016   67065   92%
2/29/2016   67168   100%
3/31/2016   67168   100%
2/29/2016   67179   100%
```

Sheet 2

```
A           B       C
Dealer Id   VDPS    % lift
66393       2,252   143%
66732       2,190 
67065       2,583 
67168       1,535 
67179       7,046 
67293       1,954 
67328       1,793
```

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant by "back out % lift", so I subtracted it, but you can adjust the formula as needed. I created a "helper" column to make each row unique to make index/match for the prior month a bit easier for each owner id.

```
Sheet 1                 
a               B          C        D           E
Date        ownerID  % Premium  Date|Owner  index/match
2/29/2016   66393   100%        =A2&"|"&B2    =IF(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),0)&"|"&B2,D:D,0))>C2,C2-INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),C2)
3/31/2016   66393   100%
2/29/2016   66732   100%
3/31/2016   66732   100%
2/29/2016   67065   0%
3/31/2016   67065   92%
2/29/2016   67168   100%
3/31/2016   67168   100%
2/29/2016   67179   100%

Sheet 2   
A        B           C
Dealer Id VDPS      % lift
66393    2,252       143%
66732    2,190 
67065    2,583 
67168    1,535 
67179    7,046 
67293    1,954 
67328    1,793
```